# Understanding the effect of curly braces with respect to redirections ("> file1 >& file2" vs. "{ > file1; } >& file2")

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Please consider the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch ./temp

set -C

>./temp &>/dev/null      # Visible error message output ("./test7: line 7: ./temp: cannot overwrite existing file")

{ >./temp; } &>/dev/null # No error message
```

Could somebody please explain why the error message which results from the redirection in the next-to-last line is not suppressed by the trailing `&>/dev/null`, while it works as expected in the last line?

I have studied the paragraphs about redirection and compound commands (notably, the section about group commands) in bash's manual, but couldn't make an explanation out of it. After all, since there is only one command in the curly braces, leaving the braces away shouldn't change anything, should it? Does the difference have to do something with the order in which bash parses lines?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. @pynexj's answer explains your problem well

Comment: However, thank you very much for your effort. Of course, I would have upvoted your answer in any case. It contained a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to bash manual (`man bash`):

> Redirections are processed in the order they appear, from  left to right. [...] Note that the order of redirections is significant.

For `> temp >& /dev/null`, when bash handles the `> temp` part, stderr is still pointing to the tty so you can see the error. You can verify like this:

```
[STEP 101] $ set -C
[STEP 102] $ date >> temp
[STEP 103] $
[STEP 104] $ > temp
bash: temp: cannot overwrite existing file
[STEP 105] $ > temp >& /dev/null
bash: temp: cannot overwrite existing file
[STEP 106] $
[STEP 107] $ >& /dev/null > temp
[STEP 108] $ 2> /dev/null > temp
[STEP 109] $
```

For `{ > temp; } &> /dev/null`, the `{ > temp; }` is handled as a compound command and its output as a whole is redirected by `&> /dev/null`.

Comment: I think I am beginning to see what you mean. Just to be sure: In the case of `>./temp &>/dev/null`, the whole thing is *one* command, but the second part of it does not get executed because the first part throws an error, thus interrupting it in the middle?

Comment: `&>/dev/null` was executed, but after the error message was already printed to the tty.

Comment: I see. Now I've got it. Thank you very much, +1 and accepted.